# Couldn't parse this elif clause

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to create a script that will check if the sub directory "Empty_Files" exists and if not then it will create it. It will then check all the regular, non hidden files in the current directory. If any of the files sizes are 0 then It will prompt the user to ask if the file should be moved. if yes then I want the file to be moved into the Move_Empty sub directory.

It says line 16 command not found and also line 32: Couldn't parse this elif clause. Fix to allow more checks. and I am not sure why
any help is appreciated

```
#!/bin/bash

#Script to move empty files from current directory into the sub directory Empty_Files

# usage:  ./move_empty


subdirectory="Empty_Files"


if [ -f $subdirectory ]  # does the Empty_Files file exist?
 then
   echo $subdirectory "exists!"
else
  mkdir -p /home/student/Empty_Files
  echo "Empty_Files subdirectory created"
  fi
   $currentfiles = ls | cat -n  # check all non hidden files in current directory


    if [ $currentfiles -eq 0 ] # check if any files are empty
   then

  echo -n "Would you like to move the file Y/N:" # if a file is empty ask the user if the want to move the file
    read $useranswer

    fi
   if [ $useranswer = "y" || "Y" ] 
   then
   mv $currentfiles /home/student/Empty_Files
 echo "mv command successful"
elif [ $useranswer = "n" || "N" ]
 echo "File will not be moved"

if [ $currentfiles !-eq 0 ]
then
echo "no empty files found in the current directory"
exit 55
fi
```

Comment: https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: The `elif` is missing its `then`, and `!-eq` isn't a valid comparison operator; you want `-ne`. There are a lot of syntax errors that shellcheck.net will point out, but most important the logic around `currentfiles` is all wrong. You need to iterate over the files (`for filename in *; do` will work), checking each one's type and size (`if [ -f "$filename" ] && [ ! -s "$filename" ]; then`), and (if that file is empty) asking about moving it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - For assigning output of a command to a variable you can use two methods:

```
var=$(Your cmd)
var=`Your cmd`
```

2 - As you mention, `var` do not need any `$` and equal sign comes with no spaces.

3 - The output of `currentfile` variable is in different lines, and `if` statement can't parse this.It's better to change it like this:

```
if [ -z "$currentfiles" ];then
```

4 - Also you should change your if statement with OR condition like this :

```
if [ "$useranswer" = "y" ] || [ "$useranswer" = "Y" ];then
```

5 - The `then` near line 32 is missing for `elif` section.

6 - After third `if` section which is come with `elif` , it needs `fi` in order to close `if` section.

7 - final `if` also look as array, so for checking in if condition, you should do something like this:

```
if [ ! -z "$currentfiles" ];then
```

8 - Your variable `currentfiles` contain line numbers . and moving to directory getting error.

```
1 file1
2 file2
3 file3
...
```

So you do need just a list like this:

```
currentfiles=$( ls . )
```

At the end, your code could be change like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
subdirectory="Empty_Files"


if [ -f $subdirectory ]  # does the Empty_Files file exist?
then
   echo $subdirectory "exists!"
else
   mkdir -p /home/student/Empty_Files
   echo "Empty_Files subdirectory created"
fi

currentfiles=$( ls . )  # check all non hidden files in current directory

for eachfile in $currentfiles
do
   checksize=$(du -sh $eachfile | awk '{print $1}')

   if [ "$checksize" = "0" ] # check if any files are empty
   then
      echo -n "Would you like to move the file Y/N:" # if a file is empty ask the user if the want to move the file
      read useranswer
   fi

   if [ "$useranswer" = "y" ] || [ "$useranswer" = "Y" ]
   then
      mv $eachfile /home/student/Empty_Files
      echo "mv command successful"
   elif [ "$useranswer" = "n" ] || [ "$useranswer" = "N" ]
   then
      echo "File will not be moved"
   fi

   if [ ! -z "$currentfiles" ]
   then
      echo "no empty files found in the current directory"
      #exit 55
   fi
done
```